# Safari does not display the div in the center of another div

Tags: html, css

I have successfully positioned a div in the center of another div but it does not work in Safari browser.

```css
#box{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
    
#inner_box {
    margin: 0;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <div id="inner_box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Safari needs the `-webkit-` prefix for `transform` …

Comment: yes, it solved the problem, please post an answer so that I could accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari (still) needs the `-webkit-` prefix for `transform`:

```
#inner_box {
    /* … */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without position:

```
#box{
 width: 100%;    
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
text-align:center;
}

#inner_box {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin-right: -50%;` isn't needed here... Also the #box div is already 100% height and width of itself.

You're already aligning the #inner-box with the top and left positioning.
Then the transform style is aligning it to the centre of the #box.

```
#box{
    position: relative;
    }

    #inner_box {
        margin: 0;    
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```